# Wifi hotspot not working on my unofficial cyanogenmod 10 (Android 4.1.2)

Tags: cyanogenmod, wifi-hotspot

On my unofficial cyanogenmod 10 custom ROM WiFi hotspot is not workingsl .Is there any other method or app to turn the WiFi hotspot on?I tried the foxfi app it didn't work.also there is no restriction that carrier applies on this.:-( :-(

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: Its karbonn titanium s5 .local OEM in india

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Wi-Fi Hotspot feature is broken in your custom ROM, then it doesn't matter what apps you install. They all rely on the OS to do their work. You need to build or find a ROM which supports this feature in order to use it.